# Locked out of Ubuntu 14.04 account after moving /home to a different partition

Tags: 14.04, mount, fstab

I moved all my data in `/home` to a different partition and deleted (foolishly) all my old `/home` data. I forgot to tell `/etc/fstab` to load the new partition as `/home`.

After restarting I can't get past the login screen. Also, I don't have any other accounts to go back and edit `fstab`.

How do I get in to my account?

Comment: Boot from a live dvd, move home back or edit fstab.

Comment: ... or from the recovery console if you don't have a live dvd - just remember you will need to remount the root partition rw in order to make your edits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boot into recovery mode and you can edit /etc/fstab from the command prompt.